# NHibernate map single table with parent / child relationship

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am experimenting with NHibernate instead of writing all my own SQL. But I already run into trouble mapping my experimental Domain model of just a few classes. The problem I am currently having is the relationships as demonstrated by the class below.

Can anyone show my how this would be mapped in NHibernate? (The XML)!

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Category> Subcategories { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the link in the accepted answer is dead here is my answer.

You can map the relation to the parent just like any other many to one relation.

```
<many-to-one name="Parent" class="Category" column="ParentId(Put the correct name of the column here)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also quite new to NHibernate. I'd suggest looking at the documentation, because there are many things with NHibernate which you should understand before writing production code.

Take a look at quick [starter guide](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx)

it shows how to install nhibernate and it's xml mapping xsd to have intellisense in Visual Studio. It also shows how to do a simple mapping that you want.
Also here's the in [depth manual](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html)

Trust me, it's always better to come to the correct solution by yourself than someone giving you a ready to go answer. at least, while you are learning a new technology.

Good luck and let us know if you'll have any other questions

P.S. as a starter, I'd recommend downloading an evaluation version of [NHibernate Profiler](http://nhprof.com/), it helped me a lot.